# RMI client cannot lookup server - java.rmi.UnmarshalException

Tags: java, rmi, policy

I have a java rmi server and a java rmi client **in two separate and different machines**.

The server is basically a fibonacy calculator. It receives a bunch of numbers and calculates a Fibonacci sequence based on them.

The client simply sends a bunch of numbers for the server to calculate.

The FiboServer project consists of three classes:

- IFibonacci.java: an interface
- Fibonacci.java: implements the previously defined interface
- FibonacciServer.java: Has the main, and runs the server

**FibonacciServer.java:**

```
package fiboserver;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class FibonacciServer {
    public static void main(String args[]){

        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "server.policy");
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }

        try{
            IFibonacci fib = new Fibonacci();

            // Bind the remote object's stub in the registry
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            registry.rebind("fibonacci", fib);

            System.out.println("Fibonacci Server ready.");
        }catch(RemoteException rex){
            System.err.println("Exception in Fibonacci.main " + rex);
        }
    }
}
```

The client project merely has one class: FibonacciClient.java.

**FibonacciClient.java:**

```
package fiboclient;

import fiboserver.IFibonacci;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class FibonacciClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        if (System.getSecurityManager() == null) {
            System.setProperty("java.security.policy", "client.policy");
            System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager());
        }

        try{
            //args[0] = server Public IP
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(args[0]);
            IFibonacci calculator = (IFibonacci) registry.lookup("fibonacci");

            //the rest of the args are just numbers to calculate
            for(int i = 1; i < args.length; i++){
                try{
                    BigInteger index = new BigInteger(args[i]);
                    BigInteger f = calculator.getFibonacci(index);

                    System.out.println("The " + args[i] + "th Fibonacci number "
                            + "is " + f);
                }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                    System.err.println(args[i] + " is not an integer.");
                }
            }
        }catch(RemoteException e){
            System.err.println("Remote object threw exception " + e);
        } catch (NotBoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not find the requested remote object on "
                    + "the server: " + e);
        }
    }

}
```

Both projects have a policy file, the server has a `server.policy` and the client has a `client.policy` file. Both files have the same content:

```
grant{
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I am launching the FiboServer in the server machine using `java -jar FiboServer.jar -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=12.34.56.789`

I am launching the client by using `java -jar FiboClient.jar 12.34.56.789 1 2 3 4 5`.

The server launches without a problem. But when I launch the client I get the error:

```
Remote object threw exception java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fiboserver.IFibonacci
```

Searches on StackOverflow convinced me that this has to do with RMI registry errors or policy file errors. However I know the the policy files are being read correctly and I do not think they have any errors.

What am I doing wrong? Why is this not working?

---

**EDIT:**

**IFibonacci.java:**

```
package fiboserver;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface IFibonacci extends Remote{
    public BigInteger getFibonacci(int n) throws RemoteException;
    public BigInteger getFibonacci(BigInteger n) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**JAR Files:**

Contents of FibonacciClient.jar:

```
|META-INF
|----Manifest.mf
|fiboclient
|----FibonacciClient.class
```

Contents of FibonacciServer.jar:

```
|META-INF
|----manifest.mf
|fiboserver
|----IFibonacci.class
|----FibonacciServer.class
|----Fibonacci.class
```

Comment: You are binding `Fibonaci` object in the remote registry but trying to  lookup `IFibonacci` object in the client. Also, does the class `IFibonacci` exist in the client??

Comment: @prasanth Every RMI program in the world does that. The implementation object isn't in the Registry, and it isn't available at the client. It's remote, and it is accessed via its remote interface. That's the whole idea.

Comment: Is the class `IFibonacci` available in server?? Are you binding the correct object in the registry and looking up the same from the client??

Comment: @prasanth If that class wasn't available at the server it wouldn't start. He is binding the correct object and looking it up correctly. Please stop guessing.

Comment: Somewhere in the client or server the mentioned class is not available. you might wanna look into it. For your information, I am not guessing. I am trying to help you by pointing out something you might have missed inadvertently

Comment: You've made at least one incorrect statement and asked several meaningless questions, all of which exhibits zero understanding of RMI. If that isn't guessing it'll have to do until the real thing comes along.

Comment: The server has the classes IFibonacci, Fibonacci and FibonacciServer. As can be seen in the server code (after a quick fix! My bad it was a typo!) the server makes `IFibonacci fib = new Fibonacci();`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolink Certainly there is evidence. The lookup() throws a ClassNotFoundException naming a class that therefore cannot be at the client, and that therefore must be associated somehow with the object returned by lookup(), either as the remote interface, which is by far the most likely scenario given the naming convention, or else as a method parameter or result type, or another non-remote interface.

Comment: How did you build the FiboClient.jar file? Can you check if it has the fiboserver.IFibonacci class?

Comment: I used the 'build and clean' button on Netbeans IDE 8. I can check that, i think. I just have to change the extension to zip and open it right?

Comment: I just checked my client's Jar. The FiboClient Jar **does not** have the other classes. It only has the FibonacciClient.class! I am missing something here. Should the client not download the missing classes from the server?

Comment: So, exactly as everybody has been telling you, the remote interface class isn't available at the client. It is up to you to fix that. You've been told how, several times.

Comment: I am known by many things, understand what people tell me at first is not one of them. I had no idea how to fix the problem, but now I know how to ! Thanks for your patience !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client doesn't have the class named in the exception available on its classpath. You need to deploy it, and any class it depends in, and so on recursively until closure.

Possibly you've renamed/copied the remote interface into another package for the client. You can't do that. It has to be the same at server and client. Same name, same methods, same package.

NB The message in your client 'remote object threw exception' isn't correct. It could be the lookup() throwing the exception. Don't confuse yourself by assuming things that may not be so. Just print the actual error message, exception, and stack trace.

Comment: Ohh man, so you're telling me the imports matter? Hold on, I will add more information to the example!

Comment: No, I'm telling you that the *package names* matter. Just read what I actually wrote.

Comment: I have added the complete code for the client, the server and the IFibonacci interface (currently in the server project). I think I did not mess up the package names. Can you confirm?

Comment: Alright, I edited my question to have more details on the projects. I think this is clear now. 

I am listening to any suggestions on how to fix this !

Comment: I am using Netbeans and it "automatically" links projects by copying code and making code available to projects that require it. Eclipse has a simillar option to "link" projects. Perhaps that is the source of the problem? If so, how can I fix it without using any IDE options?

Comment: The first thing to settle is whether fiboserver.IFibonacci is present in the client's CLASSPATH: i.e., in this case, in the client JAR file. If it isn't, put it there, as I said in the first place.

Comment: I dont follow the first question. I coded the client so i know it is the source code (sry if i am being slow here). As for the second, i will try to open the jar file and manually check if it has all the classes needed when i get home. Thanks!

Comment: I just checked my client's Jar. The FiboClient Jar **does not** have the other classes. It only has the FibonacciClient.class! I am missing something here. Should the client not download the missing classes from the server?

Comment: No, you should put that file into the JAR file. I told you that above. Several times.

Comment: Alright, I just added **all files** from the server to the client's Jar. Surely now nothing is missing !

And it works ! Finally ! Thank you so much for your help! I just wished there was a better/easier way to make my CLient's JAR without having to copy the entire server project inside of it xD

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix You don't have to copy the entire server project, and I haven't stated otherwise. You only have to include the files that are needed in the JAR file. Specifically, the remote interface, all the classes it depends on, all the classes they depend on, and so on, recursively until closure, as I said above, and the stub file, if you're generating it with `rmic.`